# Android parse JSON array of array

Tags: android, arrays, json, parsing

I have JSON code like above, as a response:

```
"candidates": [
{
  "subtest1": "0.802138030529022",
  "enrollment_timestamp": "1416850761"
},
{
  "elizabeth": "0.802138030529022",
  "enrollment_timestamp": "1417207485"
},
{
  "elizabeth": "0.777253568172455",
  "enrollment_timestamp": "1416518415"
},
{
  "elizabeth": "0.777253568172455",
  "enrollment_timestamp": "1416431816"
}
]
```

I try to get names from `candidates` array.

```
  public void dataCheck(String text){
    System.out.println("JSON response:");
    System.out.println(text);

    try {
        JSONObject jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(text);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.optJSONArray("candidates");

        for(int i=0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String subtest1 = jsonObject.optString("subtest1").toString();

        }
    } catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

It is hard, because these values are in an array of an array and without identifier. Identifier is the exact value, so couldn't define variable in my code. I need only first value, like `subtest1` in this example.

Comment: I don't see an array in an array. I see JSONObjects in an JSONArray

Comment: @ligi: Sorry, I've interpret candidates' attributes as another arrays.

Comment: it should with your code. Is there any exception ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Get the keys in the first JSON object
Iterator<?> keys = jsonObject.keys();
if (keys.hasNext()) {
    // Get the key
    String key = (String)keys.next();
    String objValue = jsonObject.getString(key);
    ...
}
```

Comment: But these variable names are given by response. I cannot define them programatically.

Comment: I should get 'subtest1', as the value of a String.

Comment: See mine updated answer. First, get all keys. If there is a key, get the value of that key. If you also want other keys and values you can replace `if` with `while`.

Comment: I think this should use `jsonRootObject` without the for loop according to my code.

Comment: But in this case how can it identify `candidates` array? That should look for key-value pairs in this array.